# Elasticsearch by geo location only if document has location

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I currently query documents from Elasticsearch with the standard `geo_distance` filter within Xmi of a pair of coordinates. Now here's where I'd like to improve: I also want to index documents WITHOUT a location and also include them in the search but not filter them by distance.

Is this possible or out of reach with Elasticsearch? Essentially, if a document has a location lets filter it and find ones nearby. Otherwise, just search the documents without location normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [Bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) wrapping the `geo_distance` filter with a [Missing filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html) both as `should`